# Trying to update column from related table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL. I have a query that pulls back values for caseAssignedTo in my table iwmsCaseDetails that are blank.  It looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    icd.caseAssignedTo,
    hed.ADUserid
FROM
    iwmsCaseDetails icd 
    INNER JOIN hremployeedetails hed on (hed.EmployeeNumber = icd.OwnerEmployeeNumber)
WHERE 
    icd.caseAssignedTo is null or trim(icd.caseAssignedTo) = '';
```

The code above pulls back the relevant records with the rows in the icd.caseAssignedTo column shown as empty, and the rows in the hed.ADUserid column showing the values that I want icd.caseAssignedTo to have.

However, the update code below does NOT work:

```
UPDATE 
    iwmsCaseDetails icd 
    INNER JOIN hremployeedetails hed 
            on (hed.EmployeeNumber = icd.OwnerEmployeeNumber)
SET
   icd.caseAssignedTo = hed.ADUserid
WHERE 
    icd.caseAssignedTo is null or trim(icd.caseAssignedTo) = '';
```

Instead it returns an error message:

> "#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

I have checked, and re-checked this SQL but cannot see why it doesn't work. Can anyone see what is wrong with it?

Comment: Check triggers,

Comment: Yep - that's got it.  There was a trigger which was storing history but had missing rows.  thanks heaps. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because there was a trigger on iwmsCaseDetails which was trying to store a copy of the data into a history table - but the history table didn't have all the requisite columns defined that were being referenced by the trigger.  After I added the missing rows, the original sql worked just fine.